# Airflow 'GoogleCloudStorageDownloadOperator' is not defined

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Importing the operator in the following way:

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_download_operator import GoogleCloudStorageDownloadOperator
```

Then trying to use it in a DAG:

```
download_file =  GoogleCloudStorageDownloadOperator(bucket='us-central1-scale-training-d7d12089-bucket',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
    object='params.json',
    filename='params.json')
```

Receiving this error:

> 'GoogleCloudStorageDownloadOperator' is not defined

Edit: I am using Google Cloud Composer so I assume the relevant dependecies are installed.

Comment: I run your code in my Cloud Composer and it worked. Do you mind adding the whole DAG so we can check it out.

Comment: Can you also let us know what version of Composer your environment is? You can use "gcloud composer environments describe <environment-name>"

Comment: I am having the same problem with these commands: from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_s3 import GoogleCloudStorageToS3Operator
from airflow.contrib.operators.s3_to_gcs_operator import S3ToGoogleCloudStorageOperator. Are the contrib operators installed by default?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, you also need to add the GCP dependency to Airflow:

`pip install apache-airflow[gcp_api]`

There's more information about installation in the docs: https://airflow.apache.org/installation.html

Comment: I'm using cloud-composer so I assume these is already installed

Comment: These are already installed, and you should not ever attempt to run "pip install apache-airflow" in Composer.